# How do I take a postgres data backup on Hasura

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, hasura

I want to take a pg_dump of my data from HasuraDB to my local machine. What is the recommended way to do this ?

Comment: Please could you add details on what resources you have already looked at.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Exec a `pg_dump` command on your Postgres container:

```
pg_dump -U username -d dbname > data.sql
```

In practice, you probably only want the data and not the hasura metadata or schema_migration information. This is a better 'data export' type command:

```
pg_dump -U username -d dbname --data-only --schema public > data.sql
```

**Option 2:**

If Postgres is running as a Docker container:

```
# Exec into the postgres container
$ docker exec -ti <postgres-id> -- /bin/bash
# Run pg_dump
root@postgres-3391217220-t7bbc:/$ pg_dump -U postgres -d postgres --data-only --schema public > db.sql
^D

# Back on your local machine, copy the dump
$ docker cp <postgres-id>:/db.sql db.sql
```

Comment: I get *"unknown command "ms" for "hasura"* with this - do I need to be running these commands from something like SSH inside the Hasura microservice/host, not locally?

Answer (score 9):

Hasura has a `pgdump` API command, enabled by default. Here are the docs: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/pgdump.html

What the docs currently lack is an example. Here's an example I use to dump the Hasura data, but not the schema (which comes from migrations) in order to import it into my locally hosted dev hasura (insert your own `hasura-admin-secret`, assuming you use one, or replace with other headers as needed):

```sh
HASURA_SECRET=som3_Secr3t_Her3
curl -d '{"-Fc", "opts": ["--data-only"]}' -H "x-hasura-admin-secret: $HASURA_SECRET" https://your-host-url.com/v1alpha1/pg_dump > dumpfile
```

Comment: I'm getting a curl: (7) Failed to connect to postgres port 443: Operation timed out error. Any clue why?

Comment: I think the docs have updated slightly since this was posted - there is now some brief example (not a full curl example). Note that the JSON in this example is invalid, and I've had no success passing `-Fc` in the `opts` array (Hasura returns `{ "path": "$", "error": "internal exception while executing pg_dump", "code": "unexpected" }`). Tx, ptim

Comment: I filed an issue a while back but there's no movement there yet: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/5671

Comment: I also had pgdump fail and removing `-Fc` / `--format custom` fixed it. I assume this is because hasura's postgres client installation is a different version than the postgresql database. A matching major version is required for this option to work.

Answer (score 6):

## 2022: Hasura v.2.1.1

To export data from a postgres/Hasura instance, we need to use Postman or a curl client to make a http POST request against a hidden Hasura endpoint `/v1alpha1/pg_dump` like so:

`http://<your-hasura-host>/v1alpha1/pg_dump`

An example `curl` command:

`curl -d '{"opts": ["-a", "-O", "-x", "--inserts", "--exclude-schema=hdb_catalog"], "clean_output": true, "source": "default"}' -H "x-hasura-admin-secret:your-admin-secret-here" http://your-hasura-host/v1alpha1/pg_dump`

The above adds a header to specify your Hasura admin secret:

```
x-hasura-admin-secret:<your admin secret key>
```

And the `-d` adds a JSON body with options ("opts") for pg_dump & Hasura's endpoint handler:

```
{
  "opts": ["-a", "-O", "-x", "--inserts", "--exclude-schema=hdb_catalog"],
  "clean_output": true,
  "source": "default"
}
```

The pg_dump options ("opts") above are:

- `-a`: data-only, not schemas
- `-O`: no ownership statements
- `-x`: no access privilege statements
- `--inserts`: use SQL statements, not psql commands
- `--exclude-schema=hdb_catalog`: no Hasura migration/metadata related records, just our data

The `clean_output` key/value removes a bunch of SET statements & comments from the dump output such as:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.4 (Debian 13.4-4.pgdg100+1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
```

`source` specifies the name of the database to dump.  Usually this would be `default` unless you changed it when setting up Hasura.

The output you get should be a single `SET` statement followed by a bunch of `INSERT INTO` statements.

This can be copy/pasted directly into Hasura Console's Data > SQL tab and run to import the dumped data.

#### References/Useful Links

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html
- https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/api-reference/pgdump.html
- https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/migrations/advanced/seed-data-migration.html

##### Notes

I needed the pg_dump as seed data to use when [applying a Hasura migration](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/migrations/migrations-setup.html#step-7-apply-the-migrations-and-metadata-on-another-instance-of-the-graphql-engine), from an old instance to a new Hasura instance.  But (in my case) the initial migration output by Hasura CLI on the old instance included a bunch of `hdb_catalog` create schema statements, which would ensure failure when applying the migration onto a new Hasura instance.  (The hdb_catalog schema/tables already exist on a new/fresh Hasura install)

To correct this, I needed to [reset migrations](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/migrations/advanced/resetting-migrations.html) on the old instance and redo the migration commands (as shown in the aforementioned link).  This new migration output didn't include the hdb_catalog schema, and could be applied OK to the new Hasura instance.

I could then just run the pg_dump output in Hasura Console SQL tab/window on the new instance to repopulate my tables.